# SQL SERVER How to combine two query on the same table that has "group by"

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, select, union

I want to combine two queries on the same table that has group by.
here is my table :

```
 Date#####   |  Value1 |  Value2 |   Value3 | Type
 23/04/2014  |  1,2    |    12,3 |    10    | Green
 23/04/2014  |  11,2   |    3    |   10,3   | Non-Green    
 24/04/2014  |  10,9   |    3    |    11    | Green
 24/04/2014  |  2,3    |    12,3 |    8     | Green
 25/04/2014  |  10     |    2    |   10,8   | Non-Green    
 25/04/2014  |  1,4    |    5    |    12    | Green
```

I want it to display:

```
 Date#####   | Count |Type
 23/04/2014  |  2    | Green
 23/04/2014  |  2    | Non-Green
 24/04/2014  |  3    | Green
 25/04/2014  |  2    | Non-Green
 25/04/2014  |  1    | Green
```

here is my first query :

```
Dim strCommand As String = "SELECT d, LW, cnt FROM(SELECT TOP 7 [date] AS d, [Type] as LW, SUM(CASE WHEN ManualAssists1 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN ManualAssists2 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN ManualAssists3 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cnt FROM tbBooth where Type = 'Green' GROUP BY [date],[Type] ORDER BY [date] DESC) x ORDER BY d ASC"
```

It display :

```
 Date#####   | Count |Type
 23/04/2014  |  2    | Green
 24/04/2014  |  3    | Green
 25/04/2014  |  1    | Green
```

my second query :

```
Dim strCommand As String = "SELECT d, LW, cnt FROM(SELECT TOP 7 [date] AS d, [Type] as LW, SUM(CASE WHEN ManualAssists1 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN ManualAssists2 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN ManualAssists3 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cnt FROM tbBooth where Type = 'Non-Green' GROUP BY [date],[Type] ORDER BY [date] DESC) x ORDER BY d ASC"
```

It display :

```
 Date#####   | Count |Type
 23/04/2014  |  2    | Non-Green
 25/04/2014  |  2    | Non-Green
```

I want to combine both query to become one, and take the date, result of green and result of non-green. Assume that I have a lot of group of date, I want it to display only the last 7 group of date based on `ASC` order. I try to add UNION between my two query. Here is my code so far:

```
Dim strCommand As String = "Select 'Test1', * from tbBooth where type ='Green' and exist(SELECT d, LW, cnt FROM(SELECT TOP 7 [date] AS d, [Type] as LW, SUM(CASE WHEN Value1 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN Value2 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN Value3 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cnt FROM tbBooth GROUP BY [date],[Type] ORDER BY [date] DESC) x ORDER BY d ASC) Union Select 'Test2', * from tbBooth where type ='Non-Green' and exist(SELECT d, LW, cnt FROM(SELECT TOP 7 [date] AS d, [Type] as LW, SUM(CASE WHEN Value1 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN Value2 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN Value3 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cnt FROM tbBooth GROUP BY [date],[Type] ORDER BY [date] DESC) x ORDER BY d ASC)
```

it give me an error Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
is ther anyway how to do it? I tried to look on other SO post but I don't have any clue to do it because both my query are complex...

Thanks in advances....

Comment: hi bro, can u provide exact column name and data? because it doesnt make sense for your query, i dont really understand how u sum the value with comma ~

Comment: they are decimal type....

Comment: so your comma is refer as decimal point right? okay

Answer (score 2):

It's not that your combined query is complex, it's just that it's wrong.

What I don't understand is why you have the WHERE Type = 'Green' and 'Non-green'.
Given what you want as result, you could just remove that where and get pretty much what you're after:

```
SELECT  d ,
        LW ,
        cnt
FROM    ( SELECT TOP 7
                    [date] AS d ,
                    [Type] AS LW ,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN ManualAssists1 >= 10 THEN 1
                             ELSE 0
                        END + CASE WHEN ManualAssists2 >= 10 THEN 1
                                   ELSE 0
                              END + CASE WHEN ManualAssists3 >= 10 THEN 1
                                         ELSE 0
                                    END) AS cnt
          FROM      tbBooth
          --WHERE     Type = 'Green'
          GROUP BY  [date] ,
                    [Type]
          ORDER BY  [date] DESC
        ) x
ORDER BY d ASC
```

Which gives:

```
2014-04-23  Green   2
2014-04-23  Non-Green   2
2014-04-24  Green   3
2014-04-25  Green   1
2014-04-25  Non-Green   2
```

I see no need to "combine" the two queries when the two queries are identical besides the 'Type' in the WHERE?

Comment: Yes, you were right,, but actually I want to take the Green type and the non-green type as an alias. I want it to become a set of data of green or set of data of Non-Green, so that I can call it and put it on my graph...

Comment: I do not understand what you're after? If you want the result combined, run it without the WHERE; if you want only for one, you add the WHERE in that situation, if you want it for multiple types, you add all the wanted types in the WHERE?

Answer (score 0):

Bro, in your code change `exist` to `exists` 
:) this should Work

**Updated:**
Add `Top 7` to select

```
Select 'Test1', * from tbBooth 
where type ='Green' and exists(SELECT **top 7** d, LW, cnt FROM(SELECT TOP 7 [date] AS d,
 [Type] as LW, 
 SUM(CASE WHEN Value1 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
    + CASE WHEN Value2 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
    + CASE WHEN Value3 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cnt 
FROM tbBooth GROUP BY [date],[Type] 
ORDER BY [date] DESC) x ORDER BY d ASC) 
Union 
Select 'Test2', * from tbBooth where type ='Non-Green' 
and exists(SELECT **top 7** d, LW, cnt FROM(SELECT TOP 7 
[date] AS d, [Type] as LW, SUM(CASE WHEN Value1 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
+ CASE WHEN Value2 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
+ CASE WHEN Value3 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cnt 
FROM tbBooth GROUP BY [date],[Type] ORDER BY [date] DESC) x ORDER BY d ASC)
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction, but it still give me an error, it say:  The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: can u check with the updated answer, add `Top 7` to your selects

Comment: I tried your code,, it can execute, but it doesn't display anything in my graph.. I called the d, Test1, and Test2 into my graph....